# Can't debugging on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge after updating to Android 7.0 Nougat

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, samsung-galaxy, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I have problem with debugging on Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge after updating to Android 7.0 Nougat.

After installation on Android and start process launching is debugging
stopped with error: "run-as: Could not set capabilities: Operation not
permitted"

On all other devices - debugging is OK.

Someone advise me how to solve this problem?

PS: I created a new issue on quality.embarcadero.com ([RSP-17948](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-17948)) - yet unanswered.

Comment: Did you try connecting your device in file transfer mode?

Comment: I have the same problem as you. In April 2016, I also solved a problem with the same device (there was Android 6.0.1). Now it is repeated this year, with only the new version of Delphi and the new version of Android.

Comment: Yes. The device is in file transfer mode.

Comment: Until Android 6.0.1 (including), it all worked the way it did.

Answer (score 2):

In menu **Run** > **Parameters...** > **Debugger**

Select "**Debug configuration - Android platform**"

Add to the "**parameters**" field:

> parameter-autolaunch

Comment: Confirmed this parameter worked for me.  Galaxy S7 Android 7.  Delphi 10.2 Tokyo